# How to select all elements above the main diagonal of matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, filtering

How to select all elements above the main diagonal of matrix? I need to create a list of them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Diagonal command has a second argument that allows listing the elements of the jth superdiagonal. So we can map over all the superdiagonals:

```
n = 4;
mat = Array[a, {n, n}];
Flatten[Diagonal[mat, #] & /@ Range[n-1]]
```

which gives a list of all the elements above the diagonal:

```
{a[1, 2], a[2, 3], a[3, 4], a[1, 3], a[2, 4], a[1, 4]}
```

Comment: Niiiiice, I learned something new

Answer (score 11):

Let's use `Span` with `Part`:

```
mat=RandomInteger[{0, 100}, {5, 5}];

Flatten[mat[[#, # + 1 ;;]] & /@ Range[5]]
```

Comment: Nice, clean, clever, and faster than the naive solution. +1

Answer (score 7):

I believe that kale's approach is the best, but it can be improved with `Join` which is considerably faster than `Flatten` on packed lists, and it is a bit cleaner when written with `Array`:

```
Join @@ Array[mat[[#, # + 1 ;;]] &, n - 1]
```

To make this into a fast function it seems that one needs a Hold attribute (pass-by-reference):

```
SetAttributes[aboveDiag, HoldFirst];
aboveDiag[a_] := Join @@ Array[a[[#, # + 1 ;;]] &, Length[a] - 1]
```

Compare timings (done in v7) with bill s's code and R.M's `upperElements` function.  (I left `MatrixQ` out of `upperElements` in these tests to eliminate overhead and level the field.)

```
n = 5000;
mat = RandomInteger[999, {n, n}];

Flatten[Diagonal[mat, #] & /@ Range[n - 1]] // Timing // First

upperElements[mat]                          // Timing // First

aboveDiag[mat]                              // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.3276
>
> 0.1872
>
> 0.02308
> ```

Not quite as superior on non-packed data, but still a good bit faster than the others.

```
n = 2000;
mat = Developer`FromPackedArray @ RandomInteger[999, {n, n}];

Flatten[Diagonal[mat, #] & /@ Range[n - 1]] // Timing // First

upperElements[mat]                          // Timing // First

aboveDiag[mat]                              // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.1404
>
> 0.0998
>
> 0.02308
> ```

---

Inspired by rasher's use of `MapIndexed`, here is another one that tests the fastest on unpacked data on my system (using last `mat` above):

```
Join @@ MapIndexed[Drop[#, #2[[1]]] &, mat] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.01996
> ```

It is much slower than `aboveDiag` on packed data.

Comment: `Join` is not only faster but better than flatten (with no second arg) if the matrix can have list elements

Comment: @Rojo Good point.

Comment: Nice tuning, as usual! 
For non-huge arrays, I use (filter matching this particular problem in this case): `FilterRules[ArrayRules[yourArrayHere], {a_, b_} /; b > a]`
Just seems... neat, if not a hot-rod.

Comment: @rasher You should post that `ArrayRules` method; it does have flair.

Comment: I don't know but I've ran this and `upperElemets` and `aboveDiag` have comparable timings for `PackedArray`. Also in packed case my `Pick` is two times faster, unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @Kuba: Not even in the same zip-code as `aboveDiag` in my tests. Even an unlikely-looking `MapIndexed` implementation smokes the `Pick` method (I tried that exact `Pick` way early on).

Comment: @Kuba Very interesting.  I know that `Pick` was improved after version 7, but I didn't expect it to be twice as fast as these alternatives.  Also, if `Part` and `SparseArray` now perform equally I wonder if `Part` has gotten slower, or `SparseArray` has gotten faster; hopefully the latter.

Comment: @rasher Which version are you running, and are you using a packed arrays?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: 9.0.1,W32, on the goofing-off cigarnetbook as usual. Yes, testing with packed arrays as generated by `RandomInteger`.

Comment: WinXP V9.0.1.0, Packed test: `0.593750, 0.421875, 0.312500` and `Pick: 0.171875`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I'm curious what the following does in your environment. It seems to trade blows with `aboveDiag` in my limited testing with packed, and dusts it pretty well with unpacked/symbolic/string arrays:
`Join @@ MapIndexed[yourArrayHere[[#2[[1]], #1]] &, 
  Span @@@ Transpose[{Range[2, n], ConstantArray[n, n - 1]}]]` (n s/b length of array of course)

Comment: @rasher I get exactly the same timings from both `aboveDiag` and your code, on both packed integers and strings.  I wonder why `MapIndexed` is faster on your system.  How does this compare?: `Join @@ MapIndexed[mat[[#2[[1]], #1 ;;]] &, Range[2, n]]` and also: `Join @@ MapIndexed[Drop[#, #2[[1]]] &, mat]`.  (The latter is the fastest on string data on my system; I shall add it to my answer.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: On packed, both get same timing +/- noise as my goofy one (span-building was left from other experiments). All three (those & mine) avg. 2-3X faster on unpacked (using `Developer``FromPackedArray` to unpack same test arrays) vs `aboveDiag`, all three and the latter smoke `Pick` in all cases I tested. Interesting, probably CPU APU & under-the-cover auto-paralleling differences...

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

`` Statistics`Library`UpperTriangularMatrixToVector `` is faster than all posted methods on packed data. Using the set up from @Mr.Wizard's answer:

```
n = 4000;
mat = RandomInteger[999, {n, n}];

(res0 = Statistics`Library`UpperTriangularMatrixToVector@mat) //   Timing // First
```

> 0.027995

```
(res1 = Join @@ MapIndexed[Drop[#, #2[[1]]] &, mat] )// Timing // First
```

> 0.158976

```
(res2 = aboveDiag[mat] )// Timing // First
```

> 0.250961

```
res0 == res1 == res2
```

> True

On unpacked data, it is slower than `Join@@MapIndexed[...]` but faster than `aboveDiag`:

```
n = 2000;
mat = Developer`FromPackedArray @ RandomInteger[999, {n, n}];

(res0 = Statistics`Library`UpperTriangularMatrixToVector@mat) // Timing // First
```

> 0.096986

```
(res1 = Join @@ MapIndexed[Drop[#, #2[[1]]] &, mat] ) // Timing // First
```

> 0.029996

```
(res2 = aboveDiag[mat] ) // Timing // First
```

> 0.384942

```
res0 == res1 == res2
```

> True

**Previous version:**

```
n = 4; mat = Array[a, {n, n}];

Statistics`Library`UpperTriangularMatrixToVector @ mat
```

> {a[1, 2], a[1, 3], a[1, 4], a[2, 3], a[2, 4], a[3, 4]}

Also

```
mat[[##]] & @@@ Subsets[Range[n], {2}]
Extract[mat, Subsets[Range[n], {2}]]
```

> {a[1, 2], a[1, 3], a[1, 4], a[2, 3], a[2, 4], a[3, 4]}

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 4;
mat = Array[a, {n, n}];

Flatten@Table[If[j > i, mat[[i, j]], {}], {i, n}, {j, n}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I liked the replacing by {} for future flattening. +1

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option for square matrices using undocumented properties of `SparseArray`, which clocks in slightly faster for me than Mr.Wizard's solution:

```
upperElements[mat_?MatrixQ] := With[{n = Length@mat}, 
    SparseArray[UpperTriangularize[mat, 1]]["NonzeroValues"] ~PadRight~ (n (n - 1)/2)];
```

This constructs a sparse strictly upper triangular matrix, extracts the non-zero values and then pads it to a length of $n(n-1)/2$, where $n$ is the dimension of the matrix (to account for any upper element that might have been zero).

For non-square matrices of dimension $m\times n$, you might try using a closed form expression for the number of upper triangular entries (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231557/calculating-number-of-non-zero-elements-in-a-lower-triangular-matrix#comment514164_231557), for instance).

Comment: How come I didn't think of padright and worried about deleting extra zeros. +1

Comment: On my system (v7) this is about six to seven times slower than `aboveDiag` with `n = 5000; mat = RandomInteger[999, {n, n}];` (and leaving out `MatrixQ` for a fair test).  What data are you testing with, and what timings do you get for my data in v9?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't have the timings right now, but it was very close to yours, but a wee bit faster. I see from the comments under yours that Kuba got similar results. I don't have v7 installed, so I can't confirm your findings.

Answer (score 2):

Variation of Nasser answer:

```
n = 4;
m = Array[a, {n, n}];
Join @@ Table[m[[ i, j]], {i, n}, {j, i + 1, n}]
```

> ```
> {a[1, 2], a[1, 3], a[1, 4], a[2, 3], a[2, 4], a[3, 4]}
> ```

just another way:

```
Join @@ Pick[
  m,
  UpperTriangularize[ConstantArray[1, {n, n}], 1],
  1]
```