# Input a square matrix and return a list of the matrix entries read by antidiagonals

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a square matrix: `{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}` and  I want to get a list:

> ```
> {1,2,4,3,5,7}
> ```

Comment: related: [41362](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41362/5478)

Comment: Oddly enough, I encountered this same need yesterday. Went with the `Reverse` and `Diagonal` approach.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A straightforward and clear solution:

```
f[m_] := Flatten@Table[m[[j, i - j + 1]], {i, Length@m}, {j, i}]

f@{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
(* {1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7} *)
```

A fast compiled version:

```
fc = Compile[{{m, _Integer, 2}}, 
   Module[{n = Length@m, res, k = 0}, 
    res = Array[0 &, Quotient[n (n + 1), 2]]; 
    Do[res[[++k]] = m[[j, i - j + 1]], {i, Length@m}, {j, i}]; 
    res], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

One can also write unobvious fast uncompiled solution:

```
f2[m_] := With[{n = Length@m}, Flatten[m][[# + (n - 1) Quotient[#2 - #^2 + #, 2]]] &[
     Round@Sqrt@N@#, #] &@Range[1, n^2 + n, 2]]

n = 1000;
m = RandomInteger[10, {n, n}];

fc[m] == f[m] == f2[m] == fm[m]
(* True *)

f[m]; // AbsoluteTiming
fc[m]; // AbsoluteTiming
f2[m]; // AbsoluteTiming
fm[m]; // AbsoluteTiming  (* ubpdqn *)
(* {1.263933, Null} *)
(* {0.035024, Null} *)
(* {0.118597, Null} *)
(* {0.310459, Null} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
f[n_] := Join @@ (Thread[{Range[#], Range[#, 1, -1]}] & /@ 
     Range[n]);
fm[mat_] := Extract[mat, f[Length[mat]]]
```

So,

```
m = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
fm[m]
```

yields:{1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7}

Answer (score 4):

```
f = Function[m,
       Flatten[
         Diagonal[Reverse[m, {2}], #] & /@ Range[Length[m], 0, -1]
       ]
    ]

f @ {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Purely (*sic*) for @Mr.Wizard's entertainment... ;D

```
f @ m_ :=
  m[[(#+#2-#3)/2,(2-#+#2+#3)/2]]&[#,#2,#2^2]&[#,Round@Sqrt@#]&[2#]& ~Array~
  (#(#+1)/2&@Length@m)
```

```
f @ {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
(* {1,2,4,3,5,7} *)
```

```
m = Range[49] ~Partition~ 7;
m // MatrixForm
f @ m
```

[image: matrix screenshot]

```
(* {1,2,8,3,9,15,4,10,16,22,5,11,17,23,29,6,12,18,24,30,36,7,13,19,25,31,37,43} *)
```

(with thanks to a [couple](https://oeis.org/A004736) of [entries](https://oeis.org/A002260) in the OEIS)

Comment: It makes my head hurt trying to follow this.  Mission accomplished I guess so +1. :-p

Answer (score 2):

another way. The idea is to take diagonal of each larger matrix. But need to rotate it by 90 degrees each time, hence the `Reverse[Transpose@mat`.

```
Flatten[(Diagonal@Reverse[Transpose@mat[[1;;#, 1;;#]]])& /@ Range[Length[mat]]]

    (* {1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another just for fun:

```
m = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};

m[[-#, # ;; 1 ;; -1]] & ~Array~ Length@m ~Flatten~ {{2, 1}} // Reverse
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`Extract` enables you to prep the indices in advance.

```
entries[A_?SquareMatrixQ] :=
 With[{indices = Flatten[
     Table[{i, j - i + 1}, {j, Length[A]}, {i, j}], 1]},
  Extract[A, indices]]

entries[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}]
(* {1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7} *)
```