# Zigzag ordered encoding of DCT co-efficients

Tags: matrix, image-processing

I am doing DCT steganography. I have obtained a matrix of DCT co-efficient. I now want to perform zig-zag ordered encoding.

The matrix is as follows

```
({
  {39, -11, 16, -1, 4, 1, 1, 1},
  {-10, 2, -2, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0},
  {11, -2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
  {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {6, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
 }
```

I want to order the elements as in the image below

[image: Zig-Zag ordering]

Comment: Have a look at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72861/2305 to get all antidiagonals (you don't want to flatten them yet though). Then you reverse every other one with either `MapAt` or `MapIndexed`, and *then* you flatten it. Reconstructing the matrix is going to be a bit more... fun.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can let *Mathematica* figure out the ordering by sorting the indices of the array.

```
Clear[cmp];
cmp[p__] := Print[p];
cmp[{x1_, x2_}, {y1_, y2_}] := (x1 + x2 < y1 + y2 ||
     (x1 + x2 == y1 + y2 && If[OddQ[x1 + x2], OrderedQ[{x1, y1}], OrderedQ[{x2, y2}]]));

ClearAll[zigzag, zigzagorder];
zigzagorder[n_Integer] := zigzagorder[n] = 
  Ordering[Flatten[Outer[List, Range@n, Range@n], 1], All, cmp]
zigzag[mat_?SquareMatrixQ] := 
  Flatten[mat, 1][[zigzagorder@Length@mat]];
```

Example:

```
m = Normal@SparseArray[{i_, j_} :> (-1)^(i + j) (10 i + j), {6, 6}];
m // MatrixForm
zarray = zigzag[m]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(*
  { 11,
   -12, -21,
    31,  22,  13,
   -14, -23, -32, -41,
    51,  42,  33,  24,  15,
   -16, -25, -34, -43, -52, -61,
    62,  53,  44,  35,  26,
   -36, -45, -54, -63, 
    64,  55,  46,
   -56, -65,
    66}
*)
```

---

*Response to comment: How to invert?*

It's relatively easy to invert the processing, since [`Ordering`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html) returns a permutation of `Range[n]` of the indices of the elements.  The inverse permutation can be obtained by calling `Ordering` on the ordering.

```
m2 = Partition[zarray[[Ordering@zigzagorder@6]], 6];
m2 == m
(*  True  *)
```

General function:

```
zpartition[array_List] := With[{n = Sqrt[Length@array]}, 
  Partition[array[[Ordering@zigzagorder@n]], n] /; IntegerQ[n]
  ];

zpartition[zarray]
(*  same as m  *)
```

Comment: can u also tell me how to convert it to original form?

Comment: @RamyaMendharkar  See the update.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a relatively nifty way to perform the zigzag:

```
(* Michael's example *)
m = Array[Function[{i, j}, (-1)^(i + j) (10 i + j)], {6, 6}];

rm = Reverse /@ m; l = Length[m] - 1;
Table[If[OddQ[k], Reverse, Identity][Diagonal[rm, -k]], {k, -l, l}]
   {{11},
    {-12, -21},
    {31, 22, 13},
    {-14, -23, -32, -41},
    {51, 42, 33, 24, 15},
    {-16, -25, -34, -43, -52, -61},
    {62, 53, 44, 35, 26},
    {-36, -45, -54, -63},
    {64, 55, 46},
    {-56, -65},
    {66}}
```

Apply `Flatten[]` if needed.