# Elegant functional equivalent to a nested loop?

Tags: functional-style

I have a square $n \times n$ matrix $m$, and need to apply a function $f$ to all elements on and above the diagonal.

This is of course easy to do using a nested table:

```
 Table[Table[f @ m[[i,j]],{i,1,n}],{j,i,n}]
```

Is there a more elegant functional equivalent to this line? Something that would be more declarative in style?

Comment: Shouldn't that read `Table[Table[f@m[[i, j]], {j, i, n}], {i, n}]`?

Comment: Somewhat related: [(41362)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41362/121), [(55659)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55659/121)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Example square matrix:

```
n = 4;

m = Range[n^2] ~Partition~ n;

m // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Operation:

```
MapAt[f, m, {#, # ;;} & ~Array~ Length @ m]     // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 f(1) & f(2) & f(3) & f(4) \\
 5 & f(6) & f(7) & f(8) \\
 9 & 10 & f(11) & f(12) \\
 13 & 14 & 15 & f(16) \\
\end{array}
\right)$

A hybrid method inspired by other answers:

```
MapAt[f, #, #2[[1]] ;;] & ~MapIndexed~ m
```

Comment: THIS is what I was looking for!!

Comment: @verse Cool.  I am still looking for a related question that may have other methods of interest.

Comment: @verse I failed to find anything closely related; perhaps my memory was bad.  I did however find two questions that combined would suggest an alternative approach, though it would not be elegant.  They are linked in a comment above.

Comment: In V8, your solution can not be executed.

Comment: @ShutaoTang That is true.  `Span` operation within `MapAt` was not enabled until version 9; see: [(31173)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31173/121)

Answer (score 7):

I would use `MapIndexed`, e.g.

```
data = Partition[Range[9], 3];
MapIndexed[If[LessEqual @@ #2, f@#1, #1] &, data, {2}]
(* {{f[1], f[2], f[3]}, {4, f[5], f[6]}, {7, 8, f[9]}} *)
```

Comment: this solution traverses the entire matrix. is there any way to only traverse the upper triangular part?

Comment: Yes, it traverse the entire matrix, which may not be a bad thing, but it only applies `f` above the diagonal. So, it still minimizes how many times you execute `f`.

Answer (score 6):

```
mapAboveDiagonal1 = With[{dim = Dimensions[#2]}, 
 MapAt[#, #2, Join @@ Table[{i, j}, {i, dim[[1]]}, {j, i, dim[[2]]}]]] &
```

or

```
mapAboveDiagonal2 = MapAt[#, #2, 
  SparseArray[UpperTriangularize[
              ConstantArray[1, Dimensions[#2]]]]["NonzeroPositions"]]&;

mm = Array[m, {5, 5}];
Row[MatrixForm /@ {mm, mapAboveDiagonal1[f, mm]}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 on second - was about to post then saw yours. Probably the most efficient way - well done.

Comment: Within `MapAt` using `Span` is quite a bit faster than enumerating positions; see: [(31173)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31173/121)

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Wizard; I keep forgetting @Kuba's great discovery:)

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to take advantage of `SparseArray` index selection:

```
f[x_] := x^2;
n = 5;
(data = RandomInteger[10, {n, n}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now apply the function `f[x]` above to only the top triangle

```
SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; i <= j :> f@data[[i, j]], 
             {i_, j_} /; i > j :> data[[i, j]]}, {n, n}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

In case another way is needed:

```
matrix = Array[m, {5, 5}];

Fold[MapAt[f, #1, {#2, #2 ;;}] &, matrix, Range[5]]
(* {{f[m[1, 1]], f[m[1, 2]], f[m[1, 3]], f[m[1, 4]], 
  f[m[1, 5]]}, {m[2, 1], f[m[2, 2]], f[m[2, 3]], f[m[2, 4]], 
  f[m[2, 5]]}, {m[3, 1], m[3, 2], f[m[3, 3]], f[m[3, 4]], 
  f[m[3, 5]]}, {m[4, 1], m[4, 2], m[4, 3], f[m[4, 4]], 
  f[m[4, 5]]}, {m[5, 1], m[5, 2], m[5, 3], m[5, 4], f[m[5, 5]]}} *)
```

Comment: You've got my +1 on this as it's nearly my own formulation.  However `Fold` proves unnecessary and slightly less clean, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for contributing interesting suggestions.

I thought I'd also attach my own solution:

```
f[m[#1, #2]]& @@@ Select[Tuples[Range @ n, 2], #[[1]] <= #[[2]] &]
```

For `n=5` the output is as follows:

> {f[m[1, 1]], f[m[1, 2]], f[m[1, 3]], f[m[1, 4]], f[m[1, 5]], 
>    f[m[2, 2]], f[m[2, 3]], f[m[2, 4]], f[m[2, 5]], f[m[3, 3]], 
>    f[m[3, 4]], f[m[3, 5]], f[m[4, 4]], f[m[4, 5]], f[m[5, 5]]}

Comment: Similar: `Extract[m, Range@n~Tuples~2~Select~OrderedQ, f]`

Answer (score 2):

```
MapThread[Compose, {Array[If[#1 <= #2, f, Identity] &, Dimensions@m], m}, 2]
```

Comment: Could also be written: `Array[If[#1 <= #2, f, # &] @ m[[##]] &, Dimensions@m]`

Answer (score 0):

For the case you gave:

```
f@UpperTriangularize@m
```

Comment: doesn't UpperTriangularize simply replace the elements below the diagonal with zeros? If so, $f$ would still be evaluated for those elements, increasing the run time. In my specific case $f$ takes a substantial amount of time to evaluate, and I must keep the total number of evaluations to a minimum

Comment: @verse: You gave none of this information in your question. :| Can you provide an examplary matrix and the function `f`? On the other hand: Did you try my approach regarding timing?

Answer (score 0):

Building upon @Jinxed's insights, this may be one of the shortest code snippets, though admittedly it isn't *efficient* code:

```
(f[#] - #) & @ UpperTriangularize@m + m
```

Comment: I believe that for this to work `f` needs to be `Listable` and also `f[0] = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to join party but not near computer...will check edit when I get chance

```
ad[m_,f_]:= Module[{n =     Length[m[[1]]], mf = Flatten[m], nf}, 
nf = List /@ Flatten[NestList[n + Rest@# &, Range[n], n - 1]];
Partition[MapAt[f, mf, nf], n]]
```

Here m is square matrix and f function to be applied.

For example,

```
MatrixForm[#] -> MatrixForm[ad[#, f]] &@Partition[Range[25], 5]
```

[image]